# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a class which contains a function which populates a private field, like this...

```
public class ActionPlan
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)] 
    public long EnterpriseID  { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public Guid  ActionPlanID { get; set; }

    private ActionPlanCategory _category;
    public ActionPlanCategory GetCategory()
    {
        // Get data and initialize _category
    }
}
```

In a view I'm trying to iterate through a Model consisting of an `IEnumerable<ActionPlan>`. But as soon as the foreach loop begins I receive the above error for the GetCategory() function. Functions aren't mapped in LINQ to Entities, so I don't really understand what the problem is. My View looks something like...

```
@model IEnumerable<ActionPlan>

@foreach (var actionPlan in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="sortable_data"><a href="#" class="jumpToMyActionPlans protected" data-plan_key="@actionPlan.Key">@actionPlan.Name</a></td>
        <td class="sortable_data">@(actionPlan.GetCategory() == null ? "NA" : actionPlan.GetCategory().ActionPlanCategoryDescription)</td>
        <td class="sortable_data" style="vertical-align: middle;"><b>@(actionPlan.GetStatus() == null ? "NA" : actionPlan.GetStatus().ActionPlanStatusDescription)</b></td>
        <td>@actionPlan.DescriptionEventCondition</td>
        <td>@actionPlan.ExpectedImpactOutcome</td>
        <td class="sortable_data">@actionPlan.LeadBy</td>
        <td class="sortable_data">@actionPlan.FormattedDeadlineString</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Note that the error is thrown as soon as the condition for the foreach is entered, before execution actually reaches this line:

```
<td class="sortable_data">@(actionPlan.GetCategory() == null ? "NA" : actionPlan.GetCategory().ActionPlanCategoryDescription)</td>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where your `Model` is generated?

Comment: @nathan you actually gave me the answer when you asked this question. The code actually attempts to order on GetCategory() before the query is enumerated, and linq of course only throws the error once it attempts to enumerate it, which is quite a bit later in the view. It's not my code so I was going nuts wondering what could be happening all the while assuming that the IQueryable object was being treated correctly before the View. Stupid. Thanks man. Voted you up, if you want to answer I'll accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the error, I assume that LINQ to Entities is being used to pull the data and that `GetCategory()` is somehow being used in the query before it's sent to the database.  If that's the case, that will be your problem.

To avoid it, you need to pull that out of the query and use that method after the SQL call is made.

Bad Example:

```
var qry = SomeContext.SomeTable.OrderBy(x => x.GetCategory().SomeMember);
```

Fix:

```
var qry = SomeContext.SomeTable.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.GetCategory().SomeMember);
```

The fix forces the SQL call to be made before ordering by the custom method.